# поисковая система catcomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Сделал поисковую систему на основе https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories только с БД, все нормально работает кроме того что никак оно не хочет искать ключевое слово из первой буквы, ставил в запрос **WHERE title LIKE '$search%'**  толку никакого

```
 <?php
   global $connection;
    $search = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['term']));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM statti GROUP BY title LIMIT 10";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $result_search= array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $result_search[] = array(
        'label' => $row['title'], 'category' => ''
        ); 

        $result_search[] = array(
        'label' => $row['discription'], 'category' => ''
        );
    }
    ?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var data = <?=json_encode($result_search)?>;

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data,
      minLength: 2
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: вы используете свою переменную `$search` или нет? сейчас вы просто выводите первые 10 записей из вашей таблицы `statti`

Comment: Запрос `WHERE title LIKE '%{$search}%'`  будет лучше. И `minLength: 2` замените на `minLength: 1`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял в чем вопрос, то вы указали плагину что бы он начинал искать после того как пользователь введет минимум 2 символа, и пытаетесь искать по первой букве - http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

```
$(function() {
    var data = <?=json_encode($result_search)?>;

    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: data,
      minLength: 1
    });
});
```